# How to get Ajax to update the amount input?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to get the price from a select options drop-down form to the amount input. I have the jQuery that will select the select value from the drop-down and I understand that I need to use Ajax to do this, I am unsure of the mechanics of Ajax and how to do it. Can I get a few pointers please?

```
<select id="selectMembership" class="cat_dropdown " name="selectMembership">
    <option type="text" value="5" selected="selected" id="amount-paypal" name="amount">5</option>
    <option type="text" value="10" id="amount-paypal" name="amount">10</option>
    <option type="text" value="20" id="amount-paypal" name="amount">20</option>    
</select>

This input needs to receive the selected value    
<input type="text" value="" id="amount-paypal" name="amount">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              

        //choose which price to use from select form
        $('select').on('change', function(){
            $('#amount-paypal').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Need ajax for what? I don't get it. EDIT: IDs must be UNIQUE!

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just spotted that too. Thanks for your attention on it though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Selector `id` must be unique,change your `id` of the textbox now it will display the price according to option box change

HTML

```
<select id="selectMembership" class="cat_dropdown " name="selectMembership">
<option type="text" value="5" selected="selected"  name="amount">5</option>
<option type="text" value="10"  name="amount">10</option>
<option type="text" value="20"  name="amount">20</option>    
</select>
<input type="text" value="" id="amount-paypal-input" name="amount">
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){              
       $('select').on('change', function(){
            $('#amount-paypal-input').val($(this).val());
        });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nW4uT/)

Comment: What is the purpose of the downvote here??? If you have something to downvote, it is the question, not this answer...

Comment: @A.Wolff i too thinking about the same,downvoters kindly tell what mistake i made

Comment: Yes thankyou, I spotted it as well. You are very kind to be helping out, very much appreciated.

Comment: @user1642545 We are glad to help you `:-)`

Comment: @SridharR just one thing, you should tell OP to then remove option duplicate IDs too which are anyway useless. Or maybe OP will read this comment... ;)

Answer (score 1):

please remove id (id="amount-paypal") attribute from option tag or use unique value . id should be unique for each element in a Html page

```
<select id="selectMembership" class="cat_dropdown " name="selectMembership">
    <option type="text" value="5" selected="selected"  name="amount">5</option>
    <option type="text" value="10"  name="amount">10</option>
    <option type="text" value="20"  name="amount">20</option>    
</select>


THis input needs to receive the selected value    
<input type="text" id="amount-paypal" name="amount">
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    //choose which price to use from select form
    $('#selectMembership').on('change', function(){

        $('#amount-paypal').val($(this).val());
    });

});
```

refer this link : http://jsfiddle.net/qwXxm/